# Node.js express server runs on localhost but having issues on Heroku host

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am having a problem with my express.js code, it is running normally for me on localhost but it isn't working for me on Heroku, I think there is some sort of bug, here is my code and the errors I faced

server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

//for __dirname 
const path = require('path')

//Render css if it wasnt included in html file
app.use(express.static('./Pages'));

//redirect link to home page
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.redirect('/home')
})

//home page response
app.get('/home', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './Pages', 'home.html'))
})

//about page response
app.get('/about', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./Pages", "about.html"))
})

//listening to port
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server is online on port: " + PORT)
})
```

On Heroku it gives an "Application error"
it logs the PORT that it is running on so I can tell that the code is running so it isn't an issue with my Procfile, it also has a "favicon.io" error and I don't know how to fix that

Here is my Heroku logs with the errors

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=candy-lounge.herokuapp.com request_id=f550b1f8-6152-4a01-97b3-81fec080fed5 fwd="(seems like an ip so i deleted it)" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-10T17:35:47.907477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=candy-lounge.herokuapp.com request_id=cf93d0a2-0d01-4952-b037-92cc733a9dd1 fwd="(seems like an ip so i deleted it)" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Have you set the PORT environment variable in heroku to `80`? Else you may need to go to `yourherokuapp.heroku.com:3000`

Comment: Can you show the error messages

Comment: i sent the logs of it in the edit

Comment: The title of the question is supposed to describe the problem you're facing, not your experience while you're trying to solve the issue.

Comment: i think heroku auto sets it, and it actually does, sometimes the port isnt 3000 , it changes, and worked for my other apps, idk about this one

Comment: well everyone left i guess, imma just delete this app, idk anymore what the hell am i supposed to do with this weird thing that doesnt work for an unknown reason

Comment: Can you see `server is online on the port: xxxx`  in the console.

Comment: yes, it does , which is the weird part as that means it should work

Comment: aaaand im alone again..

Comment: I got this, `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}` answering you with details

Comment: but i dont understand, why does it need this? my other apps work fine without this line of code, what went wrong here?

Comment: i added that, still same problem

Comment: at last try using `process.cwd()` instead of `__dirname`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225789/discussion-between-french-noodles-and-justraman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got the problem fixed,
The issue was really weird but simple, somehow heroku is case sensetive about file names so it just ran the server but it couldnt find any file that the server.js asked for